# Struggling to implement tickless support for FreeRTOS on an xmega256a3

Tags: c, embedded, avr, freertos

I'm struggling to get tickless support working for our xmega256a3 port of FreeRTOS. Looking around, trying to understand under the hood better, I was surprised to see the following line in `vTaskStepTick()`:

```
configASSERT( xTicksToJump <= xNextTaskUnblockTime );
```

I don't have `configASSERT` turned on, but I would think that if I did, that would be raising issues regularly. `xTicksToJump` is a delta time, but `xNextTaskUnblockTime`, if I read the code correctly, is an absolute tick time? Did I get that wrong?

My sleep function, patterned after the documentation example looks like this:

```
static uint16_t TickPeriod; 

void sleepXmega(portTickType expectedIdleTime) 
{ 
  TickPeriod = RTC.PER; // note the period being used for ticking on the RTC so we can restore it when we wake up 
  cli(); // no interrupts while we put ourselves to bed 
  SLEEP_CTRL = SLEEP_SMODE_PSAVE_gc | SLEEP_SEN_bm; // enable sleepability 
  setRTCforSleep(); // reconfigure the RTC for sleeping 
  while (RTC.STATUS & RTC_SYNCBUSY_bm); 
  RTC.COMP = expectedIdleTime - 4; // set the RTC.COMP to be a little shorter than our idle time, seems to be about a 4 tick overhead 
  while (RTC.STATUS & RTC_SYNCBUSY_bm); 
  sei(); // need the interrupt to wake us 
  cpu_sleep(); // lights out 
  cli(); // disable interrupts while we rub the sleep out of our eyes 
  while (RTC.STATUS & RTC_SYNCBUSY_bm); 
  SLEEP.CTRL &= (~SLEEP_SEN_bm);    // Disable Sleep 
  vTaskStepTick(RTC.CNT);  // note how long we were really asleep for 
  setRTCforTick(TickPeriod); // repurpose RTC back to its original use for ISR tick generation 
  sei(); // back to our normal interruptable self 
}
```

If anyone sees an obvious problem there, I would love to hear it. The behavior it demonstrates is kind of interesting. For testing, I'm running a simple task loop that delays 2000ms, and then simply toggles a pin I can watch on my scope. Adding some printf's to my function there, it will do the first one correctly, but after I exit it, it immediately reenters, but with a near 65535 value. Which it dutifully waits out, and then gets the next one correct again, and then wrong (long) again, alternating back and forth.

Comment: Add your loop code here, it is hard to say without seeing it. I suspect, that missing *volatile* keyword might be a problem if you are using interrupts.